# How to redirect the output of 'cat' into a different folder?

Tags: command-line, output, cat

I have a Python script, `EulerianCycle.py`, and an input file, *euleriancycle.txt*.

I am able to get the correct results by doing `py EulerianCycle euleriancycle.txt > cat euleriancycleout.txt` into the current folder (`py` is an alias for `python3`).

However, I have another folder in this current one called **outputs**, to which I want all my output files be directed.

I've tried `py EulerianCycle.py euleriancycle.txt | cd outputs/ | cat > euleriancycleout.txt`

*And* `py EulerianCycle.py euleriancycle.txt | cat >cd outputs/euleriancycleout.txt`

which gives me the **broken pipe** error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `py EulerianCycle.py euleriancycle.txt` writes to the standard output stream (which I assume it  does, since otherwise you wouldn't be able to pipe it to `cat`) then `cat` is entirely superfluous here - you can redirect  standard output directly, specifying either absolute or relative path to your output file:

```
py EulerianCycle.py euleriancycle.txt > outputs/euleriancycleout.txt
```

(note: the directory `outputs/` must already exist).

---

Neither of your other commands works the way you might imagine.

- in `py EulerianCycle euleriancycle.txt > cat euleriancycleout.txt`, the shell creates a file named `cat` in the current directory, and redirects the output of `py EulerianCycle` to it, passing **both** `euleriancycle.txt` and `euleriancycleout.txt` to it as input arguments.
- in `py EulerianCycle.py euleriancycle.txt | cat >cd outputs/euleriancycleout.txt`, the shell creates a file named `cd` in the current directory, `cat` **reads** `outputs/euleriancycleout.txt` and writes it to file `cd`, ignoring standard input from the pipe (`cat` only reads standard input when it is given no input files, or an explicit `-`).

Perhaps what you were aiming for here was to pipe the output to a *subshell* like:

```
py EulerianCycle.py euleriancycle.txt | (cd outputs; cat > euleriancycleout.txt)
```

or

```
py EulerianCycle.py euleriancycle.txt | (cd outputs && cat > euleriancycleout.txt)
```

Here, `cat` reads the subshell's standard input - which is provided by the pipe - after changing to the target directory. The second version only creates `euleriancycleout.txt` if the `cd` command succeeds; the first creates it in the current directory if the `cd` fails.

Comment: okay yes this makes sense. Your code works as intended.  I also did see a random file named "cd" in the cwd. Thanks for explaining the unintentional actions of the commands I tried as well. for @mook765, the broken pipe error is as follows:

py EulerianCycle.py euleriancycle.txt | cat >cd outputs/euleriancycleout.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.../EulerianCycle.py", line 39, in <module>
    print('->'.join(eulerian_cycle(graph)))
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Comment: @Rukhan so presumably that's because `cat` is reading (instead of writing to) the intended output file, so there's noting actually reading what your python program is sending down the pipe

Comment: @steeldriver Understood! Did not realize that cat's use is for stdin explicitly like cat EulerianCycle.py, where I was trying to make it read stdout and send it down a pipe

Comment: @Trinity `cat` will do that - if you either give it no input files, or give it `-` as a pseudo input file. But it is not needed here.

Comment: @steeldriver noted with thanks, have a great one!

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you can use:

```
EulerianCycle.py | tee euleriancycleout.txt
```

to send the content to the text file and to stdout concurrently in 2 seperate streams. In other words the content will end up both in the text file and printed in the terminal.

I always do it this way as it shows me what wrote, and saves me having to open up vim to check my work.

Comment: Note: This is meant only to provide additional context, in support of the answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the info, really useful!

Answer (score -1):

Figured out I can use `py EulerianCycle.py euleriancycle.txt | cat > euleriancycleout.txt | mv -t outputs/ euleriancycleout.txt`

OR

`py EulerianCycle.py euleriancycle.txt | cat > euleriancycleout.txt & mv -t outputs/ euleriancycleout.txt`

Still open to a possible command that will do this more concisely. :)

**edit: code presented is not efficient, see green check marked answer**